# In photoshop how can you fill each selection with its own individual gradient automatically?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient, photoshop-scripting, selections, fill

Basically, this is an oversimplified illustration that shows exactly what I want. Instead of me selecting each patch individually then apply the gradient I can just use select > color range or magic wand/inverse to make multiple selections and photoshop should automatically fill each selected patch with its own gradient. In this case, the gradient will always be the same. Is there an easy way to do this so I don't have to write a script?

Edited: For those don't know if you select all the patch and apply a gradient you will see the result like the first image.

[image]

[image]

Comment: for  one layer no for multiple layers sort of.

Answer (score 1):

Change the mode to Lighten.

This will not affect the blacks.

Now you can drag a gradient in each selection separatelly.

See the image below:

[image]

Comment: This does not work, the same gradient still applies to all 3 selections instead of 3 same but individual gradients.

Comment: Okay I understand what you are saying now. I think you misunderstood and I also didn't explain that well. I would like to use only 1 drag to achieve the same effect you are describing is this possible? So instead of 3 blue arrows I only need to do 1.

Comment: Unfortunately, You cannot do it.